# SOAP RPC response parsing

Tags: java, soap, xml-parsing

Hi I am working on an application which is consuming SOAP RPC service. I have created a client code and getting soapmessage response from SOAP service. SOAP services are designed in old technologies and not supporting JAXB or AXIS2.

My SOAPMessage response is like:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Body>
<ns1:LoginResponse soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns1="http://DefaultNamespace">
<LoginReturn xsi:type="ns1:ResultMap">
  <items xsi:type="soapenc:Array" soapenc:arrayType="ns1:ResultMapItem[2]" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
 <item>
  <key xsi:type="xsd:string">SOAP_SERVICE</key>
  <value xsi:type="xsd:string">https://somevalue</value>
 </item>
 <item>
  <key xsi:type="xsd:string">UI_SERVICE</key>
  <value xsi:type="xsd:string">https://somevalue</value>
 </item>
</items>
</LoginReturn>
</ns1:LoginResponse>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Now I have to get the value of "SOAP_SERVICE" from the map and store it into some variable. 
Can someone please suggest me something how I can proceed.

Thanks.

Adding the client code.

```
        SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();
       String url = "https://serviceUrl"; 
       String soapRequest = "requeststring";

       System.out.println("soapRequest.."+soapRequest);

      InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(soapRequest.getBytes());
      SOAPMessage request = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage(null, is);
      SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(request, url);
      ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      soapResponse.writeTo(out);
```

Comment: Question is too broad. There are so many standard ways to do it. Maybe it is time to read more about Webservices in Java? ... " I have created a client code..." - what did you use for it? JAXB, Axis2 or what?

Comment: SOAP service is designed in very old way and it is not supporting JAXB or axis2. I have used javax.xml.soap to develop client code.

Comment: I am aware of JAXB and AXis2 but here the services are developed in very old tech and I have consume those in my application and again I cant change anything in service code.

Comment: Please post your client  code so we can see how can you obtain this value

Comment: Posted the client code also.

Comment: SOAP Service does not depend on your client implementation (JAXB, Axis or anything else). That is a main purpose of WebService. Server side can be done in any language or framework, while client can be done in any other language or framework. So, better approach to do not re-invent a wheel and pick one of standard technology and do things simple. Preferable with JAXB as long as of now, it is a standard in JDK. But if you'd like to do manually, just use Xalan Xpath capability which is standard for JDK as well.

Comment: @Vadim To use JAXB we need to generate stubs and as this service is developed usin SOAP 1.1 protocol , I am not not able to generate stubs with the same. Even wsimport is also not working.

Comment: It can be a long discussion and it is possible to use JAXB "from bottom", but if you'd like to use DOM do it with Xalan Xpath functionality, to do not stuck with substrings. It is not good in general.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this might look ugly, but as you cannot use another technology, you will have to traverse the SOAP response just as a DOM object.

This means, first locate the `item` nodes. Then, go through them one by one, searching for the `item` that has a child `key` node with value `SOAP_SERVICE`.

Once found, go through `key` node children, until you find the `value` node.

Here is a working example (continued from your code)

```
    SOAPBody body = soapResponse.getSOAPBody();

    NodeList returnList = body.getElementsByTagName("item");

    for (int i = 0; i < returnList.getLength(); i++) {
        NodeList innerResultList = returnList.item(i).getChildNodes();

        for (int j = 0; j < innerResultList.getLength(); j++) {
            if ("KEY".equalsIgnoreCase(innerResultList.item(j).getNodeName()) 
                    && "SOAP_SERVICE".equalsIgnoreCase(innerResultList.item(j).getTextContent())) {
                for (int k = j +1; k < innerResultList.getLength(); k++){
                    if ("VALUE".equalsIgnoreCase(innerResultList.item(k).getNodeName())) {
                        System.out.println("Value for SOAP_SERVICE is " + innerResultList.item(k).getTextContent());
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: "but as you cannot use another technology..." - that is a false assumption made by  @user3541321. Who cares how WebService implemented on server side? SOAP is a SOAP and it is up to the client implementation what to use...

Comment: Thanks for help Cristian. Client code is developed using SOAP 1.1 and above code is not fit for SOAP 1.1. It is giving error javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: InputStream does not represent a valid SOAP 1.2 Message.